# Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 103.0 ask where so save when downloading a file

Tags: firefox

In Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu 103.0, I cannot find the configuration to let Firefox ask me, e.g., which directory a downloaded file should be saved to.

`about:config` has an option in `browser.download` part called `browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel` that some pages on the Internet claim can be set to `false` to get Firefox to ask, but after restarting Firefox I still do not get asked.

With Menu -> Edit -> Settings -> General -> File and Applications -> Applications I can set "Zip archive" to "Always ask". With this setting, I am asked whether to open with "Archive Manage" or "Save File". The "Save File" does not ask which directory to save to.

Answer (score 0):

I found the relevant configuration myself:

In `about:config` there is another option (beyond `browser.download.improvements_to_download_panel`) called `browser.download.useDownloadDir`. When this is set to false, the browser ask for the directory.

Comment: On the General Settings page, there is an "Always ask you where to save files" checkmark. Is that not doing what you are after?